# Closed form for $1^k + ... + n^k$ (generalized Harmonic number)

Tags: summation, integers

This question must have been asked, it's just very hard to search for such questions.

I'm looking for the cleanest method I can find for getting a closed form formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$

Wikipedia provides https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula which has a tantalising *"There is also a similar (but somehow simpler) expression:..."* paragraph but fails to follow up.

http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/sums-of-powers-of-positive-integers-conclusion contains a thorough "through the ages" expose, the last two entries being Pascal and Bernoulli.

However, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nUZaVCLgqA seems to contain a fresh approach that I can't find documented anywhere else. However, I find the video hard to follow.

And maybe there is some technique that is cleaner still...

I understand that "cleanest" is maybe subjective and hence it is an imperfect question, but it would be interesting to see the various alternatives (and surely there cannot be many) battle it out.

Comment: This still isn't a very well formed question. The answer to these sums is always a polynomial of degree $k+1$. There exist recursions for these polynomials and a number of *derivations* but, you're not really going to escape using Bernoulli numbers or some double sum. The only exception would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number

Comment: I believe this is a *generalized Harmonic number*, $H_{n,-k}$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Cool, but I don't see how this helps

Comment: A simple comment that helps point the poser to a reference on his question.  It also suggests the title of the problem should be modified.  That's all.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/450839/52816) excellent answer.

Comment: If you wanted this for arbitrary values, you could use zeta functions.

Answer (score 18):

**[2016-08-06]:** Connection with Stirling Numbers of the second kind added.

---

Here we derive a  method based upon *[formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* to obtain a closed formula for
\begin{align*}
S_k(n):=\sum_{j=1}^n j^k\qquad\qquad n,k\geq 1
\end{align*}

In order to do so we encode sequences $(a_j)_{j\geq 0}$ by generating functions $A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j$.

> **Constant sequence $(1)_{j\geq 0}$**
>
> We start with the *constant sequence* $(1)_{j\geq 0}$
>
> \begin{align*}
> (1)_{j\geq 0}=(1,1,1,\ldots) \quad \rightarrow \quad \frac{1}{1-z}&=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z^j\tag{1}\\
> &=1+z+z^2+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>
> We see the constant sequence is encoded by the *[geometric power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.

$$ $$

> **Getting $k$-th powers $(j^k)_{j\geq 0}$**
>
> Differentiating a power series and multiplication with $z$ results in
>   \begin{align*}
> zD_z \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j = \sum_{j=0}^\infty ja_jz^j
> \end{align*}
>   Here we denote with  $D_z:=\frac{d}{dz}$ the *[differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator)*. If we apply in (1) the operator $zD_z$ successively $k$ times, we get $k$-th powers of $j$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> (j^k)_{j\geq 0}=(0^k,1^k,2^k,\ldots)\quad\rightarrow\quad (zD_z)^k\frac{1}{1-z}&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty j^kz^j\tag{2}\\
> &=0^k+1^kz+2^kz^2+\cdots
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **Summing up $k$-th powers $\left(\sum_{j=0}^n j^k\right)_{j\geq 0}$**
>
> A nice fact is that *summing up* elements is encoded in formal power series by multiplication with $\frac{1}{1-z}$. This is due to the *[Cauchy product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)*
>   \begin{align*}
>   \frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jz^j&=\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty z^l\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jz^j\right)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{l=0}^m a_l\right)z^m
>   \end{align*}
>
> So, multiplying (2) with the *operator* $\frac{1}{1-z}$ provides a generating function for the sum of the $k$-th powers of the first $n$ numbers.
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \left(\sum_{j=0}^n j^k\right)_{n\geq 0}\quad \rightarrow \quad \frac{1}{1-z}(zD_z)^k\frac{1}{1-z}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=0}^n j^k\right)z^n\\
> &=0^k+\left(0^k+1^k\right)z+\left(0^k+1^k+2^k\right)z^2+\cdots
>   \end{align*}

It's convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$. We summarize this as

> **Method  1:**
>
> The sum of the $k$-th powers of numbers $1$ to $n$ is given by
>   \begin{align*}
> S_k(n)=\sum_{j=1}^nj^k=[z^n]\frac{1}{1-z}(zD_z)^k\frac{1}{1-z}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

A small example with $k=2$.

> **Example: $S_2(n)$**
>
> \begin{align*}
> S_2(n)=\sum_{j=0}^n j^2&=[z^n]\frac{1}{1-z}(zD_z)^2\frac{1}{1-z}\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{z(1+z)}{(1-z)^4}\\
> &=[z^n](z+z^2)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-4}{j}(-z)^{j}\tag{5}\\
> &=\left([z^{n-1}]+[z^{n-2}]\right)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{j+3}{3}z^j\tag{6}\\
> &=\binom{n+2}{3}+\binom{n+1}{7}\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we apply the *operator* $\frac{1}{1-z}(zD_z)^2$ to $\frac{1}{1-z}$
- In (5) we use the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* expansion
- In (6) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator,   apply the formula

\begin{align*}
  [z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)
  \end{align*}
and use the binomial identity
\begin{align*}
  \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q
  \end{align*}

> **Connection with Stirling Numbers of the second kind:**
>
> The  operator $(zD_z)^k$ can be expressed with Stirling Numbers of the second kind ${n\brace k}$: (see e.g. *[this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.3948v3.pdf)*)
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(zD_z\right)^k=\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}z^jD_z^j\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>
> Applying  this formula  to (3) we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^n]&\frac{1}{1-z}\left(zD_z\right)^k\frac{1}{1-z}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}z^jD_z^j\frac{1}{1-z}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}j!\frac{z^j}{(1-z)^{j+1}}\tag{8}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}j!\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{-(j+1)}{l}(-1)^lz^{j+l}\tag{9}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}j!\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{j+l}{l}z^{j+l}\tag{10}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}j!\sum_{l=0}^{n-j}\binom{j+l}{l}[z^{n-j-l}]\frac{1}{1-z}\tag{11}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}j!\sum_{l=0}^{n-j}\binom{j+l}{l}\tag{12}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}j!\binom{n+1}{j+1}\tag{13}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{j+1}}}{j+1}\tag{14}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> *Comment:*

- In (8) we differentiate $j$ times and get $D_z^j(1-z)^{-1}=j!(1-z)^{j+1}$
- In (9) we use the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series*)* expansion
- In (10) we use $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q$ again
- In (11) we do some rearrangements and use $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$ again
- In (12) we observe the contribution of the coefficient of the *geometric series* is always one.
- In (13) we use the binomial identity $\sum_{l=0}^{n-j}\binom{j+l}{l}=\sum_{l=j}^{n}\binom{l}{j}=\binom{n+1}{j+1}$
- In (14) we do some simplifications and use Don Knuths *falling factorial power* notation: $$n^{\underline{j}}=\frac{n!}{(n-j)!}$$

We summarize this as

> **Method  2:**
>
> The sum of the $k$-th powers of numbers $1$ to $n$ is given by
>   \begin{align*}
> S_k(n)=\sum_{j=1}^nj^k=\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{j+1}}}{j+1}
> \end{align*}

A small example with $k=2$.

> **Example $S_2(n)$**
>
> \begin{align*}
> S_2(n)=\sum_{j=1}^nj^2&=\sum_{j=1}^2{2\brace j}\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{j+1}}}{j+1}\\
> &={2\brace 1}\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{2}}}{2}+{2\brace 2}\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{3}}}{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}(n+1)n+\frac{1}{3}(n+1)n(n-1)\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)
> \end{align*}

---

*Hint:* Note that *[generalised harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers)* mean the sum of *reciprocal* values of $j^k$
\begin{align*}
H_{n,k}=\sum_{j=1}^nj^{-k}
\end{align*}

Comment: Super answer! The block between (2) and (3), the bottom line, is missing $z$, $z^2$, etc... I think.

Comment: @P-i-: Thanks, you're welcome! :-) Typo corrected, thanks.

Comment: Does there exists a paper of this technique?

Answer (score 5):

Put
$$
S_\ell(n):=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{\ell}
$$
and consider the identity
$$
(n+1)^{k+1}-1=\sum_{i=1}^{n}[(i+1)^{k+1}-i^{k+1}]=(k+1)S_k(n)+\binom{k+1}{2}S_{k-1}(n)+\ldots+\\+\binom{k+1}{k}S_1(n)+n.
$$
Then, if you know the sums 
for $\ell=1,\ldots,k-1$, you can calculate $S_k(n)$  with the above recursive relation.
For example,
$$
(n+1)^2-1=2S_1(n)+n\Rightarrow S_1(n)=\frac12[(n+1)^2-1-n]=\frac12n(n+1),\\
(n+1)^3-1=3 S_2(n)+3S_1(n)+n\Rightarrow S_2(n)=\frac13[n^3+3n^2+3n-n-3S_1(n)]\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow S_2(n)=\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}
$$

Comment: A more neat way would probably be to write, $$(n+1)^{k+1}-1=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}S_{i}(n)$$

Answer (score 2):

Having posted a much [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035188/methods-to-compute-sum-k-1nkp-without-faulhabers-formula) recently, I'm inclined to provide you with my somewhat unique answer.

---

$$a_p=1-p\int_0^1f(t,p-1)dt,\quad f(x,0)=x$$

$$f(x,p)=a_px+p\int_0^xf(t,p-1)dt$$

$$f(x,p)=\sum_{k=1}^xk^p$$

Easy enough to see that

$$x=\sum_{k=1}^xk^0$$

Also relatively easy to find that

$$a_1=1-\int_0^1t\ dt=\frac12\implies f(x,1)=\frac12x+\int_0^xt\ dt=\frac12x+\frac12x^2=\sum_{k=1}^xk^1$$

And you can keep going with this.  Requires very little calculus skill to do.