# proof of $1^4+2^4+...+n^4=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}$

Tags: summation

I want a 'simple' proof to show that:

$$1^4+2^4+...+n^4=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}$$

I tried to prove it like the others but I can't and now I really need the proof. Also I want a **geometric proof** for that and this one below:

$$1^3+2^3+3^3+...=(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$$

**geometric proof**: I want a proof using shapes and geometry.

Comment: Both can easily be proved by induction.

Comment: What you mean by geometric proof ?

Comment: For the second one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n-k-big2-without-i

Comment: Already answered (in general) at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801457/closed-form-for-1k-nk-generalized-harmonic-number/1801477#1801477

Comment: I mean that using shapes and geometry.

Comment: That's not completly my Question.

Comment: The linked question mentiones known geometrical proofs for $\sum k$, $\sum k^2$ and $\sum k^3$ in the question text and asks for a geometrical proof for $\sum k^4$. How is this not the same as you ask for? If you want something else then you should edit your question making it clear exactly what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align}
  & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{(i+1)}^{5}}-{{i}^{5}}}={{(n+1)}^{5}}-{{1}^{5}} \\ 
 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{5{{i}^{4}}+10{{i}^{3}}+10{{i}^{2}}+5i+1=}{{(n+1)}^{5}}-{{1}^{5}} \\ 
 & 5\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{i}^{4}}+10\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{i}^{3}}+10\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{i}^{2}}+5\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{i\,\,+\,n=}}}}{{(n+1)}^{5}}-{{1}^{5}} \\ 
 & 5{{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{i}^{4}}+10\left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)}}^{2}}+10\left( \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \right)+5\left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)+n={{(n+1)}^{5}}-{{1}^{5}} \\ 
\end{align}
by simplification,we have
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{i}^{4}}}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3{{n}^{2}}+3n-1)}{30}$$

Comment: Where is the geometric proof?

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Image source is AoPS

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

If you want "a simple proof" you can calculate the difference
$$(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)(3n^2+9n+5)-n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)$$ where the greater quantity comes from putting $n+1$ in the given formula. You can verify this is equal to $30(n+1)^4$ (you need for this some school calculation and you have this way determined the expression of $n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)+(n+1)^4$ ). And you can finish applying an immediate induction.