# Show that $\sum_{r=1}^n r^4=\frac{3n^2+3n-1}5\sum_{r=1}^n r^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Following from the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818361/proof-of-1424-n4-fracnn12n13n23n-130), I was wondering if it's possible show directly that 
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^4=\frac{3n^2+3n-1}5\sum_{r=1}^n r^2$$
without expanding the summation in full on either side.

Comment: Haven't you try to use induction by $n$?

Comment: I was hoping for a more direct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that
\begin{align}\sum_{r=1}^n r^2\sum_{r=1}^n r-\sum_{r=1}^n r^3
&=\sum_{1\le r< s\le n}rs^2+\sum_{1\le r<s\le n}sr^2\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n r \frac{r(r-1)(2r-1)}{6}+\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r(r-1)}{2}r^2\\
&=\frac56\sum_{r=1}^nr^4-\sum_{r=1}^nr^3+\frac1{6}\sum_{r=1}^nr^2,\end{align}
where $\sum r^3$ cancels so that
$$5\sum_{r=1}^nr^4=(6\sum_{r=1}^nr -1)\sum_{r=1}^n r^2=(3n^2+3n-1)\sum_{r=1}^n r^2.$$

Comment: Brilliant solution! Exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks! (+1, and accepted)

Comment: I was inspired by Barto's solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n-k-big2-without-i/61483).

Answer (score 3):

If you know that $\sum_{r=1}^n r^4$ is a multiple of $\sum_{r=1}^n r^2$ as polynomials, then you can simply evaluate their quotient at three different points and reconstruct the polynomial $\frac{3n^2+3n-1}5$ by interpolation.

This assumes that you also know that $\sum_{r=1}^n r^k$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ in $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Interesting approach. (+1)