# How to solve an interesting first order recurrence

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

I was solving some programming exercises then i stumbled upon one that involved the summation of $1, 2, 3, ..., n$. But in the problem i needed to come up with a way to sum all of the instances of such sum up to some number k, that is, find:

$\sum_{i=1}^k S(i)$ , where  $S(i) := \frac{i(i+1)}{2}$

So naturaly i found the recurrence relation:

$F(n) := F(n-1) + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, where $F(1) = 1$

But the problem is i have very little experience on solving recurrences. So I´d be glad to hear a suggestion on how to tackle it maybe just a completely different than solving the recurrence.

Comment: Try to express the sum as a third order polynomial of $n$.

Comment: The sum can be written in terms of $\sum i$ and $\sum {i^2}$, both of which have nice closed form.

Comment: There is no need to solve any recurrence. You are dealing with a telescoping sum!
$$\frac{i(i+1)}{2} = \frac{(i+2)-(i-1)} {3}\cdot\frac{i(i+1)}{2} = 
\frac{i(i+1)(i+2)}{6} - \frac{(i-1)i(i+1)}{6}
$$

Answer (score 1):

> *Hint:*
>
> - *[Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples)*
>     is often referred in this case. Two instances are
>     \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{i=1}^k i=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\qquad\qquad \sum_{i=1}^k i^2=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}
>   \end{align*}
> - See for instance *[this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801457/closed-form-for-1k-nk-generalized-harmonic-number/1802085#1802085)* for a method how to derive such formulas.