# Find the sum of the squares of the first $n$ natural numbers

Tags: summation

I've been asked to find the sum of the squares of the first $n$ natural numbers.

My initial thought was to just program a brute-force solution but I was wondering if there is a mathematical formula to come up with the answers.

I've made a table of all differences etc but I can't seem to find a suitable formula. How would I go about finding one, and is there even one?

Comment: Of course there is a formula. Try induction over $n$.

Comment: Yes, there is. Indeed, for any $k$, there is a polynomial of $n$ of degree $k+1$ that gives the sum of the first $n$ $k$-th powers.

Comment: In Wikipedia, [square pyramidal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number).

Comment: Bernoulli's trick is always handy:  Compute $\sum (i^3-(i-1)^3)$ in two ways.

Comment: We have [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), and also [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_power_sums_in_terms_of_elementary_symmetric_polynomials).

Comment: Begin with $f(n)=an^3+bn^2+cn+d$ and find $a,b,c,d$ by setting $n=1,2,3,4$ and inserting the sum in each case. If you also consider $n=0$, you immediately get $d=0$. It is not difficult to solve the emerging linear system.

Comment: @awllower Your advice clearly excesses OP's mathematical background

Comment: I asked a similar question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479552/convert-conditional-summation-to-closed-form-solution) last week, for the general case of every sum of every possible polynomial. The answer refering to "finite calculus" uses the squares as example

Comment: @E.Girgin I think this serves also as a reference for the OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get to the formula for the sum of squares of first n numbers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316/how-to-get-to-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-numbers)

Answer (score 9):

I like visual proofs. In the following, the first three shapes pile together $1^1$, $2^2$, $3^2$,  $4^2$ little cubes:

[image: visual sum of squares]

with [similar visions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1504012/257503) in:

- Claudi Alsina and Roger Nelsen, When Less is More: Visualizing Basic
  Inequalities (2009)
- Roger B. Nelsen, Proofs without words 2. More
  exercises in visual thinking (2000)
- Roger B. Nelsen, Proofs without
  words. Exercises in visual thinking (1993)

which I discuss in [Unconventional mathematics books](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1504012/257503).

The three same basic shapes, sums of squares, add up to $n(n+1)(n+\frac{1}{2})$, hence the volume (a third) you are looking for is :
$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\,.$$

Last comment:  $\int x^p \sim \frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}$, hence integration "adds" a degree. The case $p=-1$ is a bit different, but I'd argue [the $\log$ is dimensionless, i.e. a variant of $0$-degree polynomials](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13060/what-is-the-logarithm-of-a-kilometer-is-it-a-dimensionless-number/72464#72464). Similarly, summing $p$-powers often leads to $p+1$-power formulae.

Answer (score 7):

### Hint

I assume you know that $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}2$. So, it is somewhat natural to expect $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2$ to be of the form 
$$f(n)=an^3+bn^2+cn+d$$
for some $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{Q}$. (If you know calculus, this is related to the fact that $\int_0^xt^2dt=\frac{t^3}3+C$)

Now, you know 
$$f(0)=d=0$$
$$f(1)=a+b+c+d=1$$
$$f(2)=8a+4b+2c+d=5$$
$$f(3)=27a+9b+3c+d=14$$
In fact, these equations are enough to find $a,b,c,d$.(If you know linear algebra, this is a non-singular square matrix). You can play with these coeeficients to solve for $a,b,c,d$. When you did find $a,b,c,d$; you can prove that $f(n)$ indeed gives the some of first $n$ squares by showing $f(n)-f(n-1)=n^2$.

In fact, you can use this method to find the sum of cubes, or some of the fourth powers, or the sum of first powers, you only need to adjust the degree of the polynomial and the number of equations.

Comment: Personally, I like this one the best. Proof by induction doesn't tell us how to get the formula in the first plce

Comment: This argument helps discover the formula, but doesn't prove it works for all $n$. Induction is a straightforward enough approach for that. Alternatively, if you could prove that the sum of $k^{th}$ powers is always a $k+1$ degree polynomial, you'd be done in general. I'd be interested to see an argument for this.

Comment: @ZachStone $g(n)=f(n)-f(n-1)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, and it gives $m^k$ for $m=1,2,\ldots,k+1$. Thus, $g(n)=n^k$ for all $n$. So, $f(n)$ is equal to the sum of the first $n$ $k$-th powers.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's clever. For the last step, it looks like you're using the fact that summing $g(n)$ results in a telescoping series that collapses to $f(n)$. That's the detail that makes the whole thing fit.

Comment: Yes, in fact, that is no different than induction. But, intuitively telescoping sums makes a lot more sense than the abstract idea of induction to me.

Comment: I'm not surprised that you need some induction somewhere, but it's nicer if it's a simple one about telescoping series than a nasty computation. Separately, it looks like there should be a simple proof that the matrix is non-singular just by looking at row independence.

Comment: @ZachStone https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: @ZachStone: See my answer, which not only establishes what you asked, namely that the indefinite sum of any polynomial (not just $k$-powers) is a polynomial of degree $1$ higher, but also gives the most efficient way I know to compute the general formula. The way presented in this answer is much less efficient because monomials are not a good basis to use when dealing with difference and summation operations.

Answer (score 6):

Let $$B_n=1^2+2^2+..+n^2$$
$B_1=1, B_2=5, B_3=14, B_4=30, B_5=55, B_6=91$

Let $$A_n=1+2+..+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$\frac{B_1}{A_1}=1, \frac{B_2}{A_2}=\frac{5}{3}, \frac{B_3}{A_3}=\frac{7}{3}, \frac{B_4}{A_4}=\frac{9}{3}, \frac{B_5}{A_5}=\frac{11}{3}, \frac{B_6}{A_6}=\frac{13}{3},..$$
**Hypothesis:** $$\frac{B_n}{A_n}=\frac{2n+1}3$$

It is proved by induction. Then 
$$B_n=A_n\frac{2n+1}{3}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Pretty cool proof.

Comment: how do u use induction here.pz can u tell :)

Answer (score 6):

If we may assume to know that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}
 $$ we can use the [partial summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot k=n\sum_{k=1}^{n}k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k\left(k+1\right)}{2}\right)\left(k+1-k\right)
 $$ $$=\frac{n^{2}\left(n+1\right)}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^{2}-\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{4}
 $$ so $$\frac{3}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2}=\frac{2n^{2}\left(n+1\right)-n\left(n+1\right)+2n^{2}}{4}\Rightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2}=\frac{n\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}{6}.$$

Answer (score 3):

If you know the method of finite differences, it can also be applied to this problem. Let $f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & ... \\
\hline
f(n) & 1 & 5 & 14 & 30 & 55 & 91 & 140 & ... \\
\nabla n &  & 4 & 9 & 16 & 25 & 36 & 49 & ... \\
\nabla^2n & & & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13 & ... \\
\nabla^3 n & & & & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & ... \\
\end{array}
$$

Once we see that there are constant differences, we know that a polynomial of the order of those constant differences will satisfy our sequence of numbers. In this case, the constant $2$'s correspond to the third level of differences, and therefore a polynomial of the form $g(n)=an^3+bn^2+cn+d$  will be the solution.

Using $g(1)$, $g(2)$, $g(3)$, and $g(4)$, the system of equations

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a+b+c+d=1 \\ 
8a+4b+2c+d=5 \\ 
27a+9b+3c+d=14 \\
64a+16b+4c+d=30
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

results (the same system that has shown up in previous answers), and your favorite method to solve for $a,b,c$ and $d$ can be applied. In the end, the formula that results is $$g(n)=\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n r^2&=\frac 14\sum_{r=1}^n(2r)^2\\
&=\frac 14\sum_{r=1}^n\binom {2r}2+\binom{2r+1}2\\
&=\frac 14\sum_{r=1}^{2n+1}\binom r2\\
&=\color{red}{\frac 14\binom{2n+2}3}\\
&=\frac 14\cdot \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}\\
&=\color{red}{\frac 16 n(n+1)(2n+1)}\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

You can proof this by induction, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try

$${n(n+1)(2n+1)\over 6}$$

Either by induction or by computing in two different ways $k^3=((k-1)+1)^3$ for $1\leq k\leq n+1$ and adding up

Comment: Done thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1353749/21820) where I explain an efficient method for finding such formulae (asymptotically much faster than finding and solving those linear equations that other answers mention). The linked post in fact contains the complete solution to this very question. Basically we know that any polynomial function $f$ can be expressed in the form:

> $f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty D^k(f)(0) \binom{n}{k}$ where $D$ is the forward-difference operator.

This is a finite sum and the number of terms is at most one more than the polynomial degree of $f$. Note that the reason it is easier than other methods is that binomial coefficients form a nicer basis than the monomials, since:

> $D\left( \text{int $n$} \mapsto \binom{n}{k+1} \right) = \left( \text{int $n$} \mapsto \binom{n}{k} \right)$

In exactly the same manner as:

> $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}) = \frac{x^k}{k!}$

Thus the formula above (also known as Newton's formula) is nothing but the discrete version of Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution  based upon *[formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_functionhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)*. We proceed accordingly to *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801457/closed-form-for-1k-nk-generalized-harmonic-number/1802085#1802085)* which provides the solution to the sum of $k$-th powers of the first $n$ numbers
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^nj^k
\end{align*}

In the following we use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a series. We also use the *[differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator)* $D_x:=\frac{d}{dx}$.

> We obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^n j^2&=[x^n]\frac{1}{1-x}(xD_x)^2\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^n]\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^4}\\
> &=[x^n](x+x^2)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-4}{j}(-x)^{j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\left([x^{n-1}]+[x^{n-2}]\right)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{j+3}{3}x^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{n+2}{3}+\binom{n+1}{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *operator* $\frac{1}{1-x}(xD_x)^2$ to $\frac{1}{1-x}$
- In (2) we use the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* expansion
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator, apply the formula 
  \begin{align*}
    [x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)
    \end{align*}
  and use the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
    \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q
    \end{align*}