# Let $X$ denote an infinite set. Is every partitioning of $X^2$ induced by an associative operation $f:X^2 \rightarrow X$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> **Proposition.** Let $X$ denote an **infinite** set. Then for each partitioning $\Pi$ of $X$, there exists a function $f : X \rightarrow X$ whose coimage is $\Pi$.

I'd like to know whether the analogous statement holds for associative binary operations.

> **Question.** Let $X$ denote an infinite set. Is it true that for each partitioning $\Pi$ of $X^2$, there exists an associative operation $f : X^2 \rightarrow X$ whose coimage is $\Pi$?

This question occurred to me as a result of Behrouz Maleki's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1812597/42339).

Comment: You can't expect all partitions of a large set to be given as the coimage of a function to a smaller set. In particular, take $X$ to have two elements, and the discrete partition on $X\times X$. This partition is not the coimage of any function $X^2 \to X$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @IttayWeiss, you're completely right, but I'm assuming that $X$ is infinite. I've edited to emphasize this. I like the idea of focusing on the discrete partition, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the discrete partition of $X^2$, and assume it is the coimage of an associative binary operation. Then for all $a,b,c\in X$ we have $a(bc)=(ab)c$, and thus $a=ab$, and this determines the operation as projection to the left argument. Similarly, $bc=c$, and this determines the operation as projection to the right argument. This can only happen if $X$ is empty or a singleton.

Comment: Good thinking! $\;\!$